Make python steps non-interruptible
I want to make a portion of my python script non-interruptible - i.e. when a keyboard interrupt is triggered, it will wait for the line(s) to complete before interrupting.
Use-case: I am performing high dimensional KD space-partitioning, but only a relatively small portion of the space is relevant. Periodically, the program sends data out to file before deciding where to partition next. The program is interruptible and can be restarted with minimal overhead by reading in the data file - but if the program is interrupted during the write-out phase then there is a very significant risk of corrupting the data file (and wasting hours of computation time). Obviously, in the ideal scenario the program just wouldn't be interrupted and there wouldn't be a problem - but it needs to be interruptible for other (non-code related) reasons.
I guess the code would look something like this:
while continue_condition:
    process_data() # an interrupt called here interrupts the program
    with dont_interrupt: 
        read_write_operations() # an interrupt here will wait
    # An interrupt called inside the dont_interrupt context will be raised here

Edit: To clarify, the avoiding the corruption of the data file is a motivating factor, but not the main point of this exercise/question. The main point is how to allow an instruction to be completed before raising the interrupt.

You could create a context manager that set up and tore down a SIGINT handler.  Caveat: I have no idea if this would work on Windows.

See here for how this could work.

You can maybe use the suppress context manager from contextlib. But this may be a bit of an XY problem. You can just implement an atomic write to avoid the need for this altogether and make the program truly safe from the dangers you describe. Keep in mind, you can't prevent all kinds of interruptions (sigkill, power loss, etc.) -- an atomic write would save you even in the event of complete power loss.

@sytech suppress won't help, because the inner calls will have been interrupted by the KeyboardInterrupt anyway, it just suppresses the exception as it has bubbled up.

@AKX that's true. I suppose my thought was the goal was just to stop the whole program from terminating (so it could have an opportunity to recover), but I see that's not really a complete solution. In any case, I think atomic writes are the way to go, something like atomicwrites (or its own suggested alternatives) as a reasonably tested cross-platform solution.


if the program is interrupted during the write-out phase then there is a very significant risk of corrupting the data file (and wasting hours of computation time).

Instead of trying to block the program from stopping (which could occur due to any other reason such as a kernel panic, cosmic rays, janitorial unplugging, ...), I would suggest that the write-out phase makes a copy of the known good version, does the writing into the copy, and then replaces the last version with the copy.
That of course would be simplified if your file system supported e.g. snapshots or atomic writes.

This is probably the best-practice approach to the problem, and it does solve the risk of corrupting the data files. But how would you avoid losing the data to-be-written when interrupted.

I mean, if the data isn't saved, it isn't saved. If you do implement safe writes, you could then add a while True: try: save() except KeyboardInterrupt: continue else: break sort of loop, so if an interrupt attempt happens during the save, it's just re-tried until it succeeds (but this doesn't help with kernel panics, cosmic rays, etc.)
